# Создать json формат с данных полученных из бд

Tags: php, mysql, массивы, json

У меня есть код php

```
$users = $db->query("SELECT `id`,`login` FROM `users`");
```

Мне нужно эти данные преобразовать в вид:

```
{
 1: {
   id: id,
   login: login
 },
2: {
   id: id,
   login: login
 }
}
```

Подскажите как?

Comment: `json_encode($data)`, не?... Добавьте пример данных которые надо "преобразовывать"

Comment: ```SELECT * FROM `user` ```
Получаю данные, id, login

Comment: Отредактируй свой вопрос и вставь в него код.

Comment: @u_mulder готово

Comment: Это запрос, а php код где?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Автоматически образовать в json ответ mysql.

```
$sql = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `user");

$rows = array();
while($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
    $rows[] = $r;
}

$json = json_encode($rows);

echo $json;
```